# Как подставить ячейку как название листа в формулу google spreadsheet IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть две таблицы, в одной n листов с именами городов, во вторую таблицу нужно вывести часть данных из первой, как можно подставить название листа, например "Абакан-1" в функцию IMPORTRANGE, чтобы при протягивании формулы вниз автоматически переключалось на следующий город, а не прописывать вручную

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `A2&"!"&B2` - текст, состоящий из названия листа (в `A2`), и адреса ячейки (в `B2`).   `ДВССЫЛ(INDIRECT)` преобразовывает текст в ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Тоже ищу ответ на этот же вопрос.

Пока нашел вариант с костылями:

```
в А столбике название листа, в В - ячейки
в С столбике формула вида = A17&"!"&B17
И адрес этой ячейки в формуле = IMPORTRANGE("ссылка"; C17)
```